# IEEE Template. \cline error in table. Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables

I had this table working with an IEEETemplate but now when I try to build it with an IET Template I get the error that you can see on the title .. could anybody help me?

Thank very much for your time.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}[b]{|p{1cm}|l|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{0.3cm}{\textbf{j}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{k}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{l}}\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} & \textbf{h} & \textbf{i}  \\ \hline
       a  & b  & c & d & e \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: the class you are using is not generally available, I tried your code with article class and it produced no error, which suggests that the error is in code that you have not shown. Please post an example that produces the error or provide a link to the class if you can not generate the error using `article` class

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[h!]` latex usually warns about that and changes it to `[!ht]` but `[htp]` would be better

Answer (score 1):

With `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline`:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{-0.2pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{-0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}[b]{|p{1cm}|l|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{0.3cm}{\textbf{j}}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{k}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{l}}\\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} & \textbf{h} & \textbf{i}  \\ \hline
       a  & b  & c & d & e \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect \cmidrule works, thank you very much!

Comment: @Zarko try it with `\cline`, it does not work!

Comment: @Zarko If you did not test, please don't make such claims. Why would you think I'm doing such a complicate workaround?