# ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. - <template> \endtemplate

Tags: alignment

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{C at PCC}
\label{Table1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \hline \hline
 Standards &\multicolumn{2}{c}{IEEE 2014}& \multicolumn{2}{|c}{IEEE 2018}& \multicolumn{2}{|c}{IEC 27} &\multicolumn{2}{|c}{EN61-2}\\ \cline{2-4}

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

While using this I got an error:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.81 ...&\multicolumn{2}{|c}{EN61-2}\\ \cline{2-4}
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The code doesn't raise errors.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: seems related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470358/36296