# ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <template> \endtemplate - cline

Tags: cline

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{textcmds}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{C at PCC}
\label{Table1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \hline \hline
 Standards &\multicolumn{2}{c}{IEEE 2014}& \multicolumn{2}{|c}{IEEE 2018}& \multicolumn{2}{|c}{IEC 27} &\multicolumn{2}{|c}{EN61-2}\\ \cline{2-4}

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}



\end{document}
```

I use this code to generate table but is showing an error as given below. While I give `\hline` instead of `\cline{-}` it is working properly. But I need to use that `\cline`.

Comment: It should be `\\ \cline{2-4}` not `\ \cline{2-4}`

Comment: seems related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470358/36296

Comment: The `cta-author` class requires tables be input in a different way, check in the sample document. Anyway, `\cline` doesn't work for reasons linked to the jugglings that are made to comply with the required formatting.